# Why we need to put const at end of function header but static at first?

Tags: c++

I have code like this...

```
class Time
{
    public: 
        Time(int, int, int);
        void set_hours(int);
        void set_minutes(int);
        void set_seconds(int);

        int get_hours() const;
        int get_minutes() const;
        int get_seconds() const;

        static void fun() ;

        void printu() const;
        void prints();

    private:
        int x;
        int hours;
        int minutes;
        int seconds;
        const int i;
};
```

Why do I need to put `const` at last to make a function constant type but if i need to make a function, I can do this like...

```
static void Time::fun() 
{
    cout<<"hello";
}
```

Above function `fun()` is also in same class. I just want to know what is the reason behind this?

Comment: I know why `const` can't go at the front. I don't know why `static` can't go at the end...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

with a const instance method such as `int get_hours() const;`, the `const` means that the definition of `int get_hours() const;` will not modify `this`.

with a static method such as `static void fun();`, const does not apply because `this` is not available.

you can access a static method from the class or instance because of its visibility. more specifically, you cannot call instance methods or access instance variables (e.g. `x`, `hours`) from the static method because there is not an instance.

```
class t_classname {
public:
  static void S() { this->x = 1; } // << error. this is not available in static method
  void s() { this->x = 1; } // << ok
  void t() const { this->x = 1; } // << error. cannot change state in const method
  static void U() { t_classname a; a.x = 1; } // << ok to create an instance and use it in a static method
  void v() const { S(); U(); } // << ok. static method is visible to this and does not mutate this.

private:
  int a;
};
```

Comment: **this** is not available in static functions but still we can access static fun's using a object how?

Comment: @teacher static functions are accessed via the type (class), not an instance(object). And because every instance is of a certain type, we can access its type and all its functions, but it is implicit within the syntax.

Comment: This answer explains the difference between `static` and `const` functions but IMO it does not answer the author's original question, why the `const` modifier goes at the end instead of the beginning like `static`. IMO the accepted answer should be https://stackoverflow.com/a/7248970/3538313

Answer (score 16):

The **const** in the end means the function is constant, so it doesn't change the object's state.

When you put the **const** in the end, you can't change the state of the object's members.

Declaring a function **static** means it doesn't belong to the object at all, it belongs to the class type.

Putting **const** in the beginning means the return type value is a constant.

Comment: Putting static in the end means?

Comment: @ProgramCpp Means it won't compile.

Answer (score 4):

When you put const at the beginning, you're applying it to the return type. This doesn't matter if you're return type if void, but lets say you're returning `char*` that is not const. If you put const at the beginning, you'd end up with

```
static const char* MyFunction() { ... }
```

That tells me that the return type is a `const char*`, not a const function that returns a `char*`.

Putting it at the end avoids this problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is because that if you put the const first it would mean that you are returning a `const` thing from the function - i.e. a different meaning that the function is `const`

Comment: why we can't put static at end? any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It's a purely grammatical issue. `const` is a `cv-qualifier` and, when applied to a member function, must be placed after the parameter declarations. It you attempted to place it before the function name it could only be interpreted as qualifying the return type of the function.

`static`, on the other hand, is a storage class specifier and must appear before the declarator to which it applies.

These rules just flow from the way the C++ grammar is defined.

Answer (score 1):

It is because that if you put the const first it would mean that you are returning a const thing from the function

Comment: The thing that is returned do not have to be the same value every time the function is called, but the members of the object are only read during execution and not changed. So a const function keeps the member values const during execution, and does not return a constant value.

Answer (score 0):

One and another is explained a bit more in detail [here](http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyHowCppConst.html). Putting `const` after a function declaration makes the function constant, meaning it cannot alter anything in the object that contains the function.