# Declaring C++ member function as static const yields errors

Tags: c++, access-modifiers

I have the following class interface:

```
class Test
{
public: 
    Test();
    static void fun() const;

private:
    int x;
    static int i;
};
```

Test.cpp contains `fun()`'s implementation:

```
void Test::fun() const
{
   cout<<"hello";
}
```

it is giving me errors... `modifiers not allowed on static member functions`

What does the error mean? I want to know the reason why I am not able to create a function which is static as well as const.

Comment: `const` means it wont modify the instance, `static` means there is no particular instance.

Answer (score 6):

```
void fun() const;
```

means that fun can be applied to const objects (as well as non const).
Without the const modifier, it can only be applied on non const object.

Static functions by definition need no object.

Comment: `fun` can be applied on non-const objects, but it must treat the instance object as `const` (i.e. cannot mutate the instance).  What you wrote, "fun can only be applied on const objects" leads you to believe that `Test x(); x.fun()` doesn't work because `x` is not of type `const Test`.

Comment: You can apply `fun()` to non-`const` objects. `fun` will not affect the state of the object - see `strlen` for example.

Comment: "fun can also be applied on const objects." is still incorrect.

Comment: That's still not correct.  the `const` modifier means that the function will not modify the object in any way.  It has nothing to do with whether or not `fun` is being called on a const or non-const object.

Comment: Oh please... When do we need to know if a function modifies the object or not? When we have a const object.

Comment: If you want to be really precise, what `const` means for the caller is the function can be applied via a const reference or pointer-to-const. If I do `Test t; const Test &r = t;`, `r` is a const reference, but the object it refers to is *not* a const object. If `fun()` is non-const then I can't do `r.fun()` -- I am calling `fun()` on a non-const object, but I'd doing it through a pointer-to-const, and that's the problem. It's pretty common to conflate the two ideas, and talk about the referand of a const reference as "being const", but there is a difference between that and a const object.

Comment: I don't get what you want to say. No object is constant in real life. Const applies to how you access the object. Even if you have a const object you can change it through say a non-const pointer. So what matters always is the way you access it, not the object itself. In the above example in `r.fun()` the rules based on what r is apply. It has nothing to do with where it points. So I can't see how the above contributes somehow in the conversation.

Comment: `Even if you have a const object you can change it through say a non-const pointer.` You can if you want your program to exhibit undefined behavior. There is definitely a difference between const objects and const references/pointers.

Comment: Where is the undefined behavior in this?!

Answer (score 2):

A **member function being const means that the other non-const members of the class instance can't be called**.

A free function isn't a member function, so **it's not associated as to a class or class instance, so it can't be const as there is no member**.

A static function is a free function that have it's name scoped inside a class name, making it always relative to a type, but **not associated to an instance of that type, so there is still no member to get access to**.

In those two last cases, there is no point in having const access, as there is no member to access to.

Answer (score 2):

Static functions work without an instance, whereas const guarantees that the function will not change the instance (even though it requires an instance).

It may be easier to understand if you see the translated code:

```
   static void fun();
```

at the end of the day is translated to a function that takes no argument, namely

```
   void fun();
```

For the other example,

```
   void fun() const;
```

at the end of the day is translated to a function of the form

```
   fun(const Test& self)
```

Thus, `static void fun() const` has two contradictory meanings.

BTW: This translation occurs for all member functions (const or not)

Comment: You've been too demanding about precision in other people's answers to allow those claims about "translation" of functions to stand. A member function is not "translated" to a free function, still less one with a reference parameter named `self`. Free functions and non-static member functions fairly commonly don't even use the same calling convention.

Answer (score 0):

i answered this a few hours ago here: [Why we need to put const at end of function header but static at first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248917/why-we-need-to-put-const-at-end-of-function-header-but-static-at-first/7248985#7248985)

(SO system is not happy with my response. automatically converted to comment)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would help to have a simple code example.

```
class Foo {
public:
    static void static_function();
    void const_function() const;
};

// Use of static function:
Foo::static_function();

// Use of const function:
Foo f;
f.const_function();
```

The key difference between the two is that the `const` function is a *member* function -- that is, it is invoked on instances of the `Foo` class. That means you first need to instantiate an object of type `Foo`, and then that object acts as the receiver of the call to `const_function`. The `const` itself means that you won't modify the state of the object which is the receiver of that function call.

On the other hand, a `static` function is essentially a free function, where you can call it without a receiving object. Outside the scope of the class where it's defined, however, you'll need to qualify it using the class name: `Foo::static_function`.

This is why it doesn't make sense to have a function which is both `static` and `const`, as they're used in entirely different contexts. There's no need to worry about modifying the state of any object when invoking a `static` function because there *is* no receiving object -- it is simply invoked like a free function.

Comment: you can call a static function using the same syntax as any member function (i.e. `f.static_function()` is valid).

Comment: @Foo Bah Hence, "where you can call it without a receiving object". And I'm not sure how that contributes anything to the question at hand. On the contrary, it would be confusing for me to explicitly show syntax that's both irrelevant and, in my opinion, poor style.

Answer (score -4):

Because a `static` `const` function of a class does not make sense. `const` means that a thing (object/variable) stays the same. Static means that a thing `object` etc stays the same in that context.

Comment: I may be misinterpreting you, but I think you have a misconception of what `static` is.

Comment: You are referring to one of the other `static` meanings of C++ here.

Comment: The word `static` means fixed. In file context means fixed to the file, in object context means fixed to the class. A `const` function means that the object is fixed. so `static const` function does not make any sense at all. Agreed?

Comment: `Static means that a thing object etc stays the same in that context.` What thing? Static functions need no object to be called to.

Comment: @Ed: "Agreed?" No. The `static` keyword is rather overloaded in C++. None of the overloaded meanings mean "fixed". At file or namespace scope, `static` means the function or variable is not to be exposed to the linker. In function scope, `static` means the variable is created *once* for the lifetime of the program. In class scope, `static` means that the function or variable is a class member rather than an instance member function. This question is about class scope, and there is no object that "stays the same in that contents" -- there is no object, period.

Comment: @David: Please re-read - that is what I said. `static` in class content is fixed to that class (please read above). Class NOT object. Then I mentioned `const` - I did not imply at that point they are related. So `static const` does not make any sense.